# What version of python was this syntax added

Tags: python

I know it is possible to put an If/Else statement all on one line, similar to this.

```
[True if 1 else False]
```

What version of python was this added?

Comment: And it's called the "ternary operator", I might add.

Comment: Conditinal operator/expression, to nitpick. A trenary operator is simply any operator with three operads, although most languages only have this one (if any).

Comment: @jforberg: I though that was `2 < x < 4`

Comment: @Trufa: No, that's relational operator chaining, which has been valid for much longer.

Comment: @delnan: Correct. That's why it's called *the* ternary operator, to distinguish it from other ternary operators :). Actually the name may be more used in connection with the C programming language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[It was added in Python 2.5](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions).

Comment: Another link: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: @user: The statement you posted will result in `[True]` - that is a list containing the item `True`.

Comment: @user: Go to the console, type `python`, press enter, paste your code there, press enter. Some things are easy to find out yourself ;)

Comment: sorry Felix Kling I'm running archaic python.....so unfortunately that wasn't an option

Comment: @user: So you don't even have the possibility to create a Python file and run it? My point is, if you want to know if some syntax is valid then just run the code.

Comment: I get a syntax error when I run that code Felix.....I think I must have communicated this wrong.

Comment: @user: Is your version of Python 2.5 or above?  Did you check the ideone link?

Answer (score 1):

That was added in Python 2.5​.

Answer (score 1):

2.5, it's talked about on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).